# UISlider thumb image issue..!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

How can we set the thumb image of UISlider to stop once it reaches the max value .i.e once the thumb image reaches the max value(at the end) user should not be able to move the thumb image.

Comment: by max value do you mean a maximum determined by you, or the maximum set for the UISlider? the difference being say you want to restrict the slider to only go halfway until another requirement is met rather than allowing it to go all the way to the end. Which do you mean?

Comment: I mean to say that once the thumb image reaches to the end....the user should not be able to move the thumb image then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
[slider setContinuous:YES];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and then

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider*)sender {
    if ([slider value] >= [slider maximumValue]) {
      [slider setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```